# Node.js module imports working only in top level file hierarchy

Tags: node.js, import, export, es6-modules

I'm building a graphql server using express and mongoose for a middle tier service and have a project structure like,

```
-models
---user.js
---messages.js
---index.js
-resolvers/
-schema/
-index.js
```

with index.js as the entry point. I'm trying to export a module from src/models/index.js into src/models/user.js and src/models/messages.js.

I'm currently exporting a function to connect to a database from src/models/index.js into src/index.js, which is working perfectly fine. But trying to import the same export inside of the same directory (the models folder) renders the module inaccessible.

Seemingly, changing the syntax to

```
export function getDatabaseConnections (dbName) {
...
}
```

works to get the function recognized inside of src/models/user.js, but the connections variable remains undefined inside of the files regardless of the export syntax.

src/models/index.js

```
var connections = {};
const connectToDB = () => {
    return mongoose.connect(mongo_uri, { useNewUrlParser: true});
};

const getDatabaseConnections = (dbName) => {
  if(connections[dbName]) {
    return connections[dbName];
  } else {
    // if the connection object doesn't already exist, create and return
    connections[dbName] = mongoose.createConnection(mongo_uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
    return connections[dbName];
  }
};

const models = { User, Message };

export { connectToDB, getDatabaseConnections, connections };

export default models;
```

The import into src/index.js, which works.

```
import models, { connectToDB, getDatabaseConnections, connections } from './models';
connectToDB(); // this functions properly
console.log(connections) // functions
getDatabaseConnections('dbName') // functions
```

Inside of src/models/user.js

```
import { connectToDB, getDatabaseConnections, connections } from './index';
connectToDB(); // fails
console.log(connections) // fails
getDatabaseConnections('dbName') // fails
```

Inside of src/models/message.js I get TypeError: (0 , _index.getDatabaseConnections) is not a function, but I'm expecting the import to work as it does in the entry point of app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of a circular dependency on the imports. Models/index.js is importing from models/user.js, but I'm attempting to use the index module inside of user.js. There's no guarantee of order of resolution of the modules, so it shows up empty inside user.js.